# Any geospatial irrigation data for the UK?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

Are there any geospatial datasets for irrigation in the UK?
I've had a look through https://www.ceh.ac.uk/data but there isn't anything for agricultural irrigation in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

It's not spatial, but searching for irrigation on data.gov.uk I found a Defra report about water abstraction for agricultural use (link on this page): https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/agri-environment-indicators

It looks like the underlying data from the EA has not been released yet though - you could ask for it under an EIR request via enquiries@environment-agency.gov.uk
(although, because it hasn't been released as open data it probably means it's not in a single and easily available dataset at the moment)

Answer (score 2):

Quandl has the following free databases, but they are not geospatial. I hope they are a good start though.

**World Bank World Development Indicators:** https://www.quandl.com/data/WWDI
Search for "irrigation UK" in the database and you should see a dataset for % of total agricultural irrigated land in the UK.

**Organisation for Economic Co-Operation and Development:** https://www.quandl.com/data/OECD
Search for "irrigation UK" in the database and you should see datasets for England and Wales showing total freshwater and fresh groundwater irrigation.

**Geo3 Data Compendium:** https://www.quandl.com/data/GEOCOMP
Search for "irrigation UK" in the database and you should see a dataset for Irrigated Land in Great Britain and Northern Ireland.

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]